# virtual directory created when downloading file using Get-AzureStorageBlobContent

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage

When I am downloading Azure blob using  Get-AzureStorageBlobContent, the downloading also creates directories in terms of the blob's virtual path. Is there a way not to create the directories?

For example:

my blob: container/a/b/c.jpg

```
$blob = Get-AzureStorageBlob  -Blob $BlobName -Container $ContainerName -Context $ctx -ErrorAction Stop

$blob | Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Destination "."
```

The result is :

> ./a/b/c.jpg

which creates folder along the blob's virtual path.

I just want to have a file "c.jpg" under my current directory ".".
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

> which creates folder along the blob's virtual path.

As you said, using Get-AzureStorageBlobContent cmdlet to download a blob with a virtual directory structure into local computer, which will create same folder structure on local computer.

```
$StorageAccountName = "accountname"
$StorageAccountKey = "accesskey"

$ContainerName = "imagecontainer"

$BlobName = "a/b/c.jpg"

$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey

$blob = Get-AzureStorageBlob  -Blob $BlobName -Container $ContainerName -Context $ctx -ErrorAction Stop

$blob | Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Destination '.'
```

It seems that the Get-AzureStorageBlob and [Get-AzureStorageBlobContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603508.aspx) cmdlets do not enable us to download and save the blob named “a/b/c.jpg” as “c.jpg” into local destination directory.

As a workaround, you could refer to the following snippet using [Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603695.aspx) cmdlet to copy the blob to a new blob, and then you could download the new blob.

```
Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -SrcBlob $BlobName -DestContainer $ContainerName -SrcContainer $ContainerName -Context $ctx -DestBlob 'c.jpg'
```